# Как сделать коллаж на html css

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как перетащить нижнее фото в центр

```css
.blocks__images {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 180px;
  .block__image-img {
    margin-right: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="blocks__images">
  <div class="block__image">
    <img src="img/10.png" alt="10" class="block__image-img">
    <img src="img/11.png" alt="11" class="block__image-img">
    <img src="img/12.png" alt="12" class="block__image-img">
    <img src="img/14.png" alt="14" class="block__image-img">
    <img src="img/13.png" alt="13" class="block__image-img">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44377343/css-only-masonry-layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    .container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1140px;
}
.block_img {
    padding: 10px;
    display: grid;
    height: 100vh;
    grid-gap: 10px;
    grid-template-areas: 
    "box1 box2 box3 box4"
    "box1 box5 box5 box4"
    ;
}
.img_box img{
    border-radius: 30px 0 30px 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.box1 {
    grid-area: box1;
}
.box2 {
    grid-area: box2;
}
.box3 {
    grid-area: box3;
}
.box4 {
    grid-area: box4;
}
.box5 {
    grid-area: box5;
}
    <div class="container">
        <div class="block_img">
            <div class="img_box box1">
                <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2021/12/21/03/54/street-6884533__340.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="img_box box2">
                <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2021/03/26/11/41/couple-6125690__340.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="img_box box3">
                <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/06/07/02/16/fantasy-5268744__340.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="img_box box4">
                <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2021/12/21/03/54/street-6884533__340.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="img_box box5">
                <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2019/10/08/09/23/ferret-4534480__340.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]